Get rid of Json Parse Error Problem due to Double Enum
I have written an enum, key and value pair below;
public enum DoubleEnum {
  ZERO_PERCENT(0.0),
  ONE_PERCENT(1.0),
  EIGHT_PERCENT(8.0),
  FIFTEEN_PERCENT(15.0),
  TWENTY_PERCENT(20.0);

  private final Double value;

  TaxBracket(Double value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public static DoubleEnum fromValue(Double value) {
    for (DoubleEnum doubleEnum : DoubleEnum.values()) {
      if (doubleEnum.value.equals(value)) {
        return doubleEnum;
      }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown : " + value);
  }
}

however when ı postman request sending value of DoubleEnum; 15.0, I got errorResponse;
[org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.example.model.enums.DoubleEnum` from Floating-point value (token `JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT`)]

How can ı fix that problem? Any help would be appreciated thank you
I do not know how to fix it?
